# Select waiting on what?

Tags: redhat, python, strace

I have a python 2.7 app running on RHEL 6 that occasionally hangs.  If I strace the app, I get this repeatedly:

```
[pid 180442] select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {10, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 180442] select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {10, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
```

What is it that this select is waiting on?  Is there a filehandle hidden in there someplace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No filehandles. [man select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html):

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
           fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);

nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1
```

readfds, writefds and exceptfds are all empty (NULL)

timeout is 10 seconds.

So it is simply waiting on nothing.

Comment: Interesting, then any ideas as to how to proceed?  Does this point to a bug in the python code?